# Kafka Producer 0.9.0 performance, large number of waiting-threads

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, producer

We are writing messages at the rate of about 9000 records/sec into our kafka cluster, at times we see that the producer performance degrades considerably and then it never recovers. When this happens we see the following error "unable to allocate buffer within timeout". Below are the JMX producer metrics taken when the process is running well and when it reaches the bad state. The "waiting-threads" metric is very high when the process degrades, any inputs would be appreciated.

The producer parameters are

```
batch.size=1000000
linger.ms=30000
acks=-1
metadata.fetch.timeout.ms=1000
compression.type=none
max.request.size=10000000
```

Athough the buffer is fully available the errors are "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to allocate memory within the configured max blocking time"

[image: kafka producer metrics - degraded vs good state]

Comment: I'm not experienced with this topic, but from my unexperienced viewpoint, it seems like this question might be better suited for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). Maybe you should read their [on topic page](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) to see if you think your question could get more attention there. Again, I'm not experienced with your topic, but your question stood out to me as being a possible good question for Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

at one point you are starting to send batches of 1.000.000 messages I think that that's why you performance gets degraded. Try lowering that number or set the linger.ms lower.

Comment: yeah, the batch size is 1M, it works ok for a while before I hit the degradation, I have tried with batch size of 500K and it still is the same issue. From the metrics there is about 32M buffer available, however the error says "unable to allocate buffer within timeout"

Comment: your linger.ms is on 30000, that means that either you send a full batch or you wait 30 seconds, have you tried lowering this number? I think that your error is a bottleneck type of situation.

Comment: I think it is likely a bug in the kafka poducer 0.9.0 version. Whenever the BufferPool throws "Failed to allocate memory within the configured max blocking time", it should also do a this.waiters.remove(moreMemory);. Otherwise the waiting thread count will never get to 0 after the exception and batching will not occur